# Why another PC on lan can ping me even when I use /30 subnet?

Tags: networking, routing, switch

Here is the set up:
PC A : IP address : 192.168.1.2 Netmask : 255.255.255.252 Gateway: 192.168.1.1
PC B : IP address : 192.168.1.220 Netmask : 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.1.1
PC B is able to successfuly ping PC A.
Based on what I thought, the process should be as follows:

1. PC B pings PC A as normal because PC A IP address is considered to be on the same network from PC B point of view.
2. PC A recieves the ICMP echo request, and wants to reply.
   From PC A's point of view, PC B is on another network, so in order for a packet to reach it, it should be sent to the gateway,
3. PC A sends the echo reply packet to 192.168.1.1.
4. The gateway sees that there's a packet's sender is in the same
   subnet as the receiver, so it discards the packet as there's no
   routing to be done.
5. Thus the reply from A to B is never reached.

But apparently I'm wrong because I can clearly see that B is able to ping A.
PC A and PC B are connected using Ethernet cables to an ADSL modem.
Why is PC B able to ping PC A?
Where I'm thinking it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First PC B must obtain PC A MAC address so it either ARPs or it has already received a gratuitous ARP.  Either way it has the MAC address and yes it will send the ping to PC A. PC A receives it because it is directed at its MAC and IP addresses.

PC A should now send the response to the gateway as you say.  The frame will have PC B's IP address but the gateway's MAC address.  A gateway is a router.  It receives the packet and it knows where to send it.  Again it may need to ARP.  Anyway the gateway routes the packet and it will be directed to PC B's MAC address this time.  PC B recieves this packet because the MAC and IP address match its own.
The gateway may also send an ICMP redirect to PC A.  PC A should ignore this because from its perspective PC B is off-net.

In conclusion, your point 4 is where your description fails, a router will route back onto a source subnet unless configured not to.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is PC B able to ping PC A?

Because PC B can send packets to PC A without resorting to going outside it's local network due to the subnet mask it's using - by giving it a /24 you're saying that 192.168.1.1-255 addresses don't need to go to the gateway to access them.

Comment: That's right, I'm saying that why " PC A's Response" reaches PC B? the steps 3, 4, 5 won't happen you say?

Comment: because the return address needs no gateway either

Comment: depends. frpm PC A's point of view, it needs. because of /30 sub net mask, it thinks that 192.168.1.220 is on another network so sends it to it;s gateway

Answer (score 0):

> The gateway sees that there's a packet's sender is in the same subnet as the receiver, so it discards the packet as there's no routing to be done.

This likely depends on what kind of device your gateways is and how the gateway is configured. But, assuming your gateway device is using a /24 netmask, any router/switch/firewall will see the packet come in and forward the packet to the correct destination.

If you configured your gateway with a /30 as well, then the reply would not be able to get there - but then PC B would likely be having connectivity issues to anything.

Comment: If I could remember correctly, routers will route between subnets, not if they receive a packet where the destination and source address are in the same subnet.

Comment: A router will route based on it's routing table. In this case, the router has a route for the destination address since it's directly connected.